# selected target on parent div element click is not working in mobile view whereas works in webview

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a div containing few divs in it. On parent div click I will get the target and can get the selected target on the parent div.

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <div id="child1">content goes here</div>
    <div id="child2">content goes here</div>
</div>

document.getElementById('parentDiv').addEventListener('click',function(event{
var selectedElement = event.target.id;
}),false)
```

Here I'm able to get the selected Element in the webview. But while using this in mobile app. It is unable to get the target element. Is that because of screen size ?

I'm facing this issue which is unresolved in mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Besides your syntax error, function(event) - I'm guessing it's not your real code :-) Have you tried the touch events for mobile devices?

```
document.getElementById('parentDiv').addEventListener("touchend", function(event) { ... }), false)
```

Comment: No I haven't tried it. I have just shown the sample code of mine and not the real code. I will check with this.